# What memory do spark.*.memory properties control - RAM or disk?

Tags: apache-spark

You can set `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory` that are described as follows:

```
spark.driver.memory 1g Amount of memory to use for the driver process 

spark.executor.memory 1g Amount of memory to use per executor process (e.g. 2g, 8g).
```

The above configuration says memory. So Is it RAM memory or disk?

Comment: 100% positive when the word memory is mentioned in any programming-related document, it always refers to the main memory of the system which is RAM, and the word disk is used if a long term storage drive is involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I must admit it's a very intriguing question)

Shortly, it's **RAM** (and honestly Spark does not support disk as a resource to accept/request from a cluster manager).

From the official documentation [Application Properties](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties):

> Amount of memory to use for the driver process, i.e. where SparkContext is initialized. (e.g. 1g, 2g).
>
> Note: In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point. Instead, please set this through the --driver-memory command line option or in your default properties file.